# custom messge usage in python

Tags: rospy, custom-message

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i wrote a smal python node

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import rospy
from ros_agv.msg import MotorStates 
from ros_agv.msg import MotorCmds 
from ros_agv.msg import MotorState
from ros_agv.msg import MotorCmd
rospy.init_node('motor')
pub = rospy.Publisher('motorStates' , MotorStates)
rate = rospy.Rate(50)

while not rospy.is_shutdown():
  msg = MotorStates
  motor1 = MotorState
  msg.state = [motor1,motor1,motor1,motor1]
  
  pub.publish(msg)
  rate.sleep()
```

package.xml

```
<build_depend>message_generation</build_depend>
<exec_depend>message_runtime</exec_depend>
```

cmakelist.txt

```
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  rospy
  std_msgs
 message_generation
)
add_message_files(
  FILES
  MotorCmd.msg
  MotorState.msg
  MotorCmds.msg
  MotorStates.msg
)
generate_messages(
DEPENDENCIES
std_msgs  # Or other packages containing msgs
)

catkin_package(
  CATKIN_DEPENDS message_runtime
#  INCLUDE_DIRS include
#  LIBRARIES ros_agv
CATKIN_DEPENDS rospy
#  DEPENDS system_lib
)
```

the output of `~/ws$ rosmsg list | grep ros_agv` is

```
ros_agv/MotorCmd
ros_agv/MotorCmds
ros_agv/MotorState
ros_agv/MotorStates
```

when i try to start the node in the same terminal `rosrun ros_agv motor.py` i get the output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/anton/ws/src/ros_agv/script/motor.py", line 4, in <module>
    from ros_agv.msg import MotorStates 
  ImportError: cannot import name 'MotorStates' from 'ros_agv.msg' (unknown location)
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/364223/custom-messge-usage-in-python/) by [duck-development](https://answers.ros.org/users/22870/duck-development/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1999 on 2020-10-27

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Weasfas](https://answers.ros.org/users/34184/weasfas/) on 2020-10-27**:
Hi @duck-development  have you include in the CMakeLists.txt the `message_generation` and `message_runtime` dependencies? Also have are you using the `generate_messages` directive? Just as said [here](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/CreatingMsgAndSrv#Creating_a_msg).

**Comment by [duck-development](https://answers.ros.org/users/22870/duck-development/) on 2020-10-27**:
Yes i did otherwise this message would not be listed in rosmsg, I add the pgk.xml and cmake file to the quetion

**Comment by [Weasfas](https://answers.ros.org/users/34184/weasfas/) on 2020-10-30**:
Mm, that is weird. Maybe is something related with the workspace set up or the fact that you are using `python3` and the interpreter may not be properly set up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

One reboot of the system did help, it was a vm I never rebooted. Sorry for disturbing @Weasfas.

---

Originally posted by [duck-development](https://answers.ros.org/users/22870/duck-development/) with karma: 1999 on 2020-10-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0